# Pandas, how to check which date_range values are in pd.Interval column's time range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, intervals, between

I have a dataframe that represents (multiple) hour intervals that are not free:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'reserved': [
                        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,8), pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,12), closed='left'),
                        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,13), pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,21), closed='left')
                    ],
        'value': [1, 2]
})

|    | reserved                                   |   value |
|---:|:-------------------------------------------|--------:|
|  0 | [2011-11-09 08:00:00, 2011-11-09 12:00:00) |       1 |
|  1 | [2011-11-09 13:00:00, 2011-11-09 21:00:00) |       2 |
```

I have to find out hours that are not reserved from 07:00 - 23:00.
Something like this:

```
working_hours = pd.date_range('2021-11-09 07', '2021-11-09 23', freq='1H')

DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-09 07:00:00', '2021-11-09 08:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 09:00:00', '2021-11-09 10:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 11:00:00', '2021-11-09 12:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 13:00:00', '2021-11-09 14:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 15:00:00', '2021-11-09 16:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 17:00:00', '2021-11-09 18:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 19:00:00', '2021-11-09 20:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 21:00:00', '2021-11-09 22:00:00',
               '2021-11-09 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

Which of working_hours is not part of df.reserved interval?
In example above, we can see that `2021-11-09 07:00:00` is not reserved, `2021-11-09 12:00:00` is not reserved, as well as hours `2011-11-09 21:00:00 - 2011-11-09 22:00:00`.

I hoped that I will be able to do something like this:

```
pd.Timestamp(2021,11,9,8) in df.reserved
```

But this always return `False`.

What I need is: `working_hours not in df.reserved` in order to get:

```
2021-11-09 07:00:00
2021-11-09 12:00:00
2011-11-09 21:00:00
2011-11-09 22:00:00
```

How to do that?

Comment: There is a package that would help you work with intervals, check out https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/case_studies/calendar.html

Comment: yea, I feel the piso package works quite nicely for interval operations such as this

Comment: Pandas should be OK for this task as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions, if no match is returned `-1`, so possible filter `working_hours`:

```
i = pd.IntervalIndex(df.reserved)
s = pd.Series(working_hours[i.get_indexer(working_hours) == -1])
print (s)
0   2011-11-09 07:00:00
1   2011-11-09 12:00:00
2   2011-11-09 21:00:00
3   2011-11-09 22:00:00
4   2011-11-09 23:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Use [`IntervalIndex.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.contains.html) in [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) and flter `range` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
working_hours = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,7), 
                              pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,23), freq='1H')

i = pd.IntervalIndex(df.reserved)
m = (working_hours.map(lambda x: not i.contains(x).any()))

s = working_hours.to_series()[m].reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0   2011-11-09 07:00:00
1   2011-11-09 12:00:00
2   2011-11-09 21:00:00
3   2011-11-09 22:00:00
4   2011-11-09 23:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: It is not working. :(
working_hours = pd.date_range('2021-11-09 07', '2021-11-09 23', freq='1H')
i = IntervalIndex([[2021-11-11 07:00:00, 2021-11-11 09:00:00), [2021-11-11 09:00:00, 2021-11-11 11:00:00), [2021-11-11 11:00:00, 2021-11-11 12:30:00), [2021-11-11 13:00:00, 2021-11-11 15:00:00), [2021-11-11 15:00:00, 2021-11-11 18:00:00), [2021-11-11 18:00:00, 2021-11-11 19:00:00), [2021-11-11 19:00:00, 2021-11-11 21:00:00), [2021-11-11 21:00:00, 2021-11-11 23:00:00)],
              closed='left',
              name='reserved',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')

Comment: i.contains(pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,9))

array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])

Getting falses all the time with both approaches. Pandas is 1.1.3

Comment: Looks my "i" variable contains list of list of intervals which is wrong.

Comment: @user3225309 I have exatly same problem and solution is use `working_hours = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,7), 
                              pd.Timestamp(2011,11,9,23), freq='1H')` instead `working_hours = pd.date_range('2021-11-09 07', '2021-11-09 23', freq='1H')`

Comment: @jezrael, what is reason nit idea, but I guess some bug, intervals are still new in pandas, so bugs are expected.

Comment: do you have maybe another idea how to find intervals that are not reserved? I have a working day from 7 am to 11 pm, and from/to information for reserved intervals (can transform to any format) for each resource. At end I would like to have information like resource A is free from A-B, C-D. What do you suggest for such use case?

Comment: @user3225309 - hmmm, `do you have maybe another idea how to find intervals that are not reserved?` So need something more like in question? Or for some reason not working my solution? Can you explian more?